# Using multi thread in Nao robot

Tags: c++, multithreading, robotics, nao-robot

I am trying to do something with Nao's red ball detection API. I want do everything step by step. I wrote callbackMutex every at the beginning of callbacks. I unsubscribe event in the callback in if statement.

Functions work but sometimes gives "INFO: Thread limit reached" error or unsubscribe event error.

Nao always see red ball but create many thread(i think). How can i use only one thread?

I writing in c++.

I subscribe like this:

```
memory.subscribeToEvent("redBallDetected", "moduleName", "fuctionName");
```

then when Nao sees the ball, this function called.

```
void moduleName::functionName()
{
ALCriticalSection section(callbackMutex);
//create some proxies and declare some variables

try
{
//do movements
}
catch(const ALError& e) {
        qiLogError("module.name") << e.what() << std::endl;
      }
}
```

I use setWalkTargetVelocity to walk robot and check in if statement if it walks or stops. I didn't use any thing to start or stop a thread.

Comment: Can you show us some code that produces your error?

Comment: I don't know which lines produce this error but i add some codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's tricks:

- You should check that you never be stuck too long in your callback, 
  so calling async walk method is a good thing.
- The walk method takes time, you shouldn't call it too often: ~400ms is a minimum
- when arriving in your callback, don't wait for a previous callback to finish, just leave, as fresher info would be receive next time. I mean, past info is of no interest when receiving a new one, so don't be stuck.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How i can leave previous callback. I just subscribe it. When Nao sees the ball, it automatically enter the callback. Ball is always in view so what can i do? There is resource manager api but i didn't understand how can i use it. There isn't enough example.

Comment: Which method should i you and is there any method for release redball proxy after update information?

Comment: Just destroy your object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qi::Strand](http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/api/cpp/base/actor.html?highlight=strand#qi::Strand) to queue calls so that extra threads don't need to be created. In combination with modern subscription to ALMemory events, it looks like this:

```
qi::Strand strand; // Store the strand anywhere, but keep it alive.
qi::AnyObject redBallSubscriber; // You must also keep alive this object to keep the subscription
redBallSubscriber = memory.subscriber("redBallDetected");
redBallSubscriber.connect("signal", strand.schedulerFor([]
{
  // The strand guarantees only one thread will enter this function
  // at a time, you don't need to use a mutex here.
  try
  {
    //do movements
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e) {
    qiLogError("module.name") << e.what();
  }
}));
```

Note: if the lambda does not work, try to wrap it in a boost::function.